No sound in 24.04 LTS, Sound settings list "No Output Devices"
I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on a Dell XPS 9320 (not dual-boot). Since I upgraded from 22.04 last month, my internal speakers have not worked. In Settings, Sound Output lists "No Output Devices". I do get sound via USB devices (speakers or earbuds). I've tried many suggestions from many related questions (see below), but none have worked. Now I'm reaching out for help (please and thank you). From my reading of the related questions, here's relevant information for my case.
Based on remarks of V1del, a forum moderator at archlinux. I tried the following 4 commands to diagnose:
$ sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*

                 USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  jim        2555 F.... wireplumber
/dev/snd/seq:        jim        2549 F.... pipewire


$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 2: Speaker (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ pactl list cards
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

$ sudo pactl list sinks
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

I guess the two "Connection failure" are a problem, but I don't know what they mean.
Based on my research the past few weeks, the following also seem relevant to diagnosing my problem.
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)

and
$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake Imaging Signal Processor driver: N/A
  Device-2: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-48-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active

I don't see a sound problem in that output (the Device-1 line makes sense, as my camera doesn't work (Cheese, Skype); but that is not my focus here). I do see a problem from the next command I tried
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i snd

[    4.672746] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    4.672907] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    6.313507] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    6.313627] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    7.384054]  SDW0-Capture: ASoC: error at snd_soc_link_prepare on SDW0-Capture: -61
[    7.393206]  SDW0-Capture: ASoC: error at snd_soc_link_prepare on SDW0-Capture: -61
 … repeated 20+ times 
[   77.199398]  SDW0-Capture: ASoC: error at snd_soc_link_prepare on SDW0-Capture: -61
[   77.207304]  SDW0-Capture: ASoC: error at snd_soc_link_prepare on SDW0-Capture: -61

When I google "SDW0-Capture: ASoC: error at snd_soc_link_prepare on SDW0-Capture: -61" I see many posts (often Archlinux) that talk about downgrading the kernel. I don't know what that is, and it sounds bad (like a duct-tape fix, a patch not a fix). But maybe useful to note my kernel:
$ uname -r
6.8.0-48-generic

Please note that pipewire seems fine:
$ systemctl --user status pipewire
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-11-10 08:43:39 EST; 2h 36min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 2549 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18626)
     Memory: 3.4M (peak: 3.8M)
        CPU: 77ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1001.slice/user@1001.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─2549 /usr/bin/pipewire

Nov 10 08:43:39 xps-13plus-xps-9320 systemd[2530]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.

I think wireplumber's only problem is with the camera:
$ systemctl --user status wireplumber
● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-11-10 08:43:39 EST; 2h 37min ago
   Main PID: 2555 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 18626)
     Memory: 4.3M (peak: 5.5M)
        CPU: 348ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1001.slice/user@1001.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
             └─2555 /usr/bin/wireplumber

Nov 10 08:43:39 xps-13plus-xps-9320 systemd[2530]: Started wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager.
Nov 10 08:43:40 xps-13plus-xps-9320 wireplumber[2555]: SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.manager' could not be loaded; is it installed?
Nov 10 08:43:40 xps-13plus-xps-9320 wireplumber[2555]: PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing or broken. libcamera not supported.

Maybe this info about pipewire-pulse is relevant?
$ systemctl --user status pipewire-pulse
○ pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ pipewire-pulse.socket 

I got changes, but no fix, with the following:
$ systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire-pulse pipewire

In Settings (Sound Output), this turned "No Output Devices" to "Dummy Output" in the Output of Sound. It also changed the cards and sinks listings, as follows:
$ pactl list cards
Card #46
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
        api.alsa.card.name = "sof-soundwire"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
        device.description = "Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-sof_sdw"
        device.nick = "sof-soundwire"
        device.plugged.usec = "5766876"
        device.product.id = "0x51c8"
        device.product.name = "Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "34"
        object.id = "46"
        object.serial = "46"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "sof-soundwire"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Intel Soundwire SOF"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_sdw"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel Alderlake-P HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:8086281c,80860101,00100000 cfg-spk:4 cfg-amp:2 spk:rt1316 mic:rt715-sdca"
        alsa.id = "sofsoundwire"
        device.string = "0"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: off

and
$ pactl list sinks
Sink #39
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: auto_null
    Description: Dummy Output
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 49808 /  76% / -7.15 dB,   front-right: 49808 /  76% / -7.15 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        node.name = "auto_null"
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        audio.rate = "48000"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        factory.name = "support.null-audio-sink"
        node.virtual = "true"
        monitor.channel-volumes = "true"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "36"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "39"
        object.serial = "39"
    Formats:
        pcm

Thank you in advance to any kind soul who can help me restore my speaker sound. And I'd be happy to share more info if it would help ...
PS If it helps, here is a sampling I other questions I've looked at for help:
Fixing No Sound (Dummy Output) Issue in Ubuntu 24.04 From the top answer there, I used sudo gedit to create /etc/modprobe.d/audiofix.conf and put in the lines
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-amic enable=yes

After rebooting, no change.
No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 looks relevant, but it is about pulseaudio and 24.04 uses pipewire.
Fixing No Sound (Dummy Output) Issue in Ubuntu 24.04 suggests to downgrade the kernel, but that sounds bad to me. And my sound problem is "No Output Devices", not "Dummy Output"
I see several unanswered questions that may be about the same as mine, with no speaker-sound in 24.04; e.g. lenovo M90a, Ubuntu 24.04, missing sound on speakers, earphones ok
In my case aplay lists a sound card, so my problem differs from many other dealing with no sound in 24.04, such as No sound after upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04.
No sound in internal Speakers in Ubuntu 24.04 sounded promising, but the fix there was to disable fast-boot in Windows (I don't have Windows).
===
Here's more info,
 tail "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf"
    options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
    # Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
    options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
    # Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
    options snd-pcsp index=-2
    # Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
    options snd-usb-audio index=-2
    # options snd-hda-intel model=auto -- tried & failed for audio 
     fix 27Oct2024
    # blacklist snd_soc_avs
    options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi

As suggested by heynnema, here are two more pieces of info
    $ uname -r

6.8.0-48-generic

and
$ ls -al /boot
total 188920
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Nov  1 07:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Oct 27 09:24 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   287493 Sep 27 13:21 config-6.8.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   287459 Sep 27 08:22 config-6.8.0-48-generic
drwx------  4 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Nov  1 07:53 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Nov  1 07:52 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 72110854 Oct 27 09:24 initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 72097106 Nov  1 07:52 initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Nov  1 07:52 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   142796 Apr  8  2024 memtest86+ia32.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   143872 Apr  8  2024 memtest86+ia32.efi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   147744 Apr  8  2024 memtest86+x64.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   148992 Apr  8  2024 memtest86+x64.efi
-rw-------  1 root root  9061992 Sep 27 13:21 System.map-6.8.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  9063891 Sep 27 08:22 System.map-6.8.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Nov  1 07:52 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 14956936 Sep 27 14:47 vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 14952840 Sep 27 08:26 vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Nov  1 07:52 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic

I updated my bios to the most recent (from 2.10 to 2.16.1) but that seems not to have affected anything.
video card seems to be Intel
$  lspci | grep VGA.
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 0c)

As suggested by @hynnema, I used Mainline to change kernels to 6.5.11 and added "options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi" to alsabase.conf and rebooted (kernel 6.5.11) but still No Output Devices in Sound Settings. But now pipewire has a problem:
pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-11-21 16:12:25 EST; 9min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 2932 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18609)
     Memory: 3.4M (peak: 3.8M)
        CPU: 88ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1001.slice/user@1001.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─2932 /usr/bin/pipewire

Nov 21 16:12:25 xps-13plus-xps-9320 systemd[2911]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Nov 21 16:12:25 xps-13plus-xps-9320 pipewire[2932]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files

I plan use Dell's system restore, but first I need to back up my data and my legacy software programs.

Try this... remove your audiofix.conf file. Edit alsa-base.conf and add "options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi" (no quotes) to the end of the file. Reboot. See if the sound works and see what the Sound control panel reports now. Report back.

I can't find an audiofix.conf file. I added the line to the end of alsa-base.conf and rebooted. Sound Settings still say no output device. Thanks for the suggestion.

YOU created the audiofix.conf file at "I used sudo gedit to create /etc/modprobe.d/audiofix.conf". You MUST delete this file if my patch has any chance of working. Show me "tail /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf".

Turns out I removed the audiofix.conf file after it didn't work. I'll add the tail output at the end of my question, above.

In your alsa-base.conf file, what it this... "# options snd-hda-intel model=auto -- tried & failed for audio
fix 27Oct2024". Remove it, reboot, and retest sound.

And... "# blacklist snd_soc_avs".

If you boot to a Ubuntu 24.04 USB flash drive, does the sound work? What does the Sound control panel indicate?

I removed those lines from alas-base.conf and rebooted; still no sound. I'm now getting 24.04 on a USB, hoping to try that soon.

Booting from USB sound did not work. Sound settings listed Dummy Output as the sound device.

Try creating a 24.10 USB flash drive and see if it makes any difference. I want to try and eliminate a kernel issue. You may still need a patch like mine to get rid of Dummy Output, but of course you can't do that on a flash drive, only a real installation. Ventoy may allow that though. https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html Report back.

Same result from 24.10.  I also tried Ventoy, but was not able to make a USB that would boot.

I suspect a kernel problem at this point. Edit your question and show me "uname -r" and "ls -al /boot". Temporarily comment out my patch in alsa-base.conf. At the GRUB menu, if you select the oldest kernel showing, does the sound come back? Go to https://github.com/bkw777/mainline and follow the brief instructions at the INSTALL heading. We'll use the "mainline" tool in our next step.

Use the "sudo dmidecode -s bios-version" to determine your current BIOS version, then go to the Dell website to see if there's a newer version.

Check this solution. It might work in your case too.

Did you install the "mainline" application? If so, start it the same way that you start any application, and take a look around. I'll give more instruction later.

Do you have a Nvidia video card? Show me "dkms status". Turn off Secure Boot in your BIOS.

I've got mainline working; it shows a long list, with 6.8.0-48.48 Running and many more Installed. video card is Intel (see end of question, above). $ dkms status ipu6-drivers/0~git202406240945.aecec2aa-0ubuntu2~24.04.1, 6.8.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed

Installing a lower kernel from mainline may effect your use of the ipu6 dkms module (What is that, by the way?), and VirtualBox. But, for testing purposes, it'll serve its purpose. First, turn off SECURE BOOT in your BIOS. Then, in mainline, you can select (single click) on a kernel (not any of the FC kernels) and click INSTALL. Then reboot. Test sound. Since you're running 6.8.0 kernel now, select one of (6.7.10, or 6.6.51, or 6.5.11). Report back. So as I don't miss your comments, begin your comments with "@heynnema", no quotes.

@heynnema Secure Boot off, I used Mainline to Install 6.5.11  and rebooted, but the kernel did not change (still 6.8.0-49-generic). Mainline shows many earlier kernels Installed, with 6.8.0-49.49 Running. I am missing some step(s),

@jimgreen At the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, and then choose the 6.5.11 kernel (not recovery). Test the sound. You may need to use my earlier patch if there are still problems with the sound. Report back.

@heynnema I cannot find the GRUB menu. ESC at boot-up takes me to a grub command-line prompt; there, TAB lists many lines of possible commands, but I don't find menu.

@jimgreen Try the SHIFT key at boot time.

@heynnema The SHIFT key (press or hold) had no effect on the boot process. F12 gives me various options, but no GRUB menu. BTW I used flash drives to boot 20.04 LTS and still no sound; that showed a much earlier kernel (5...). Since the older Ubuntu releases also don't see my speakers, maybe I have a hardware problem?

@jimgreen Do you dual boot... ie: Windows or Ubuntu? I suspect not. The timing of the ESC/SHIFT key is important, and you should be tap-tap-tapping the SHIFT key at the critical timing point. It may take a few attempts before you catch it correctly. Try a few more times.

@jimgreen Did your XPS come with Windows, or Ubuntu, or both? In briefly looking at support.dell.com, I found the Ubuntu restore disk ISO image at https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=NFCXC. We may need to try installing Ubuntu 22.04 back to factory, as Dell supplies extra software for Ubuntu to make it work on their Dells, and that's what may be missing on your computer.

@heynnema Dell xps 9320 came pre-loaded with Ubuntu. I have the system-restore on USB, but it will reformat, so I need some time to confirm my backups. Also I will try more with the ESC timing. It's likely to be tomorrow before I'm ready to try the restore. Thanks for you efforts here!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

On September 2024 I have to change model to dell-headset-multi on my Dell Precision. So open conf:
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Find line starting with
options snd-hda-intel model

Change it to
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi

I have following "extra" lines there too
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1

Edit blacklist:
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

And add just this line:
blacklist snd_soc_avs

Get rid of old stuff:
sudo apt purge *pulseaudio*
sudo apt purge pipewire-media-session

Re-install new one:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pipewire pipewire-audio-client-libraries wireplumber

Reboot
Check everything is running (green):
systemctl --user status pipewire
systemctl --user status wireplumber
systemctl --user status pipewire-pulse

no need to edit grub, no need to switch to nvidia proprietary drivers (HDMI Audio, nouveau works fine)

You mention 2 "extra" lines in alsa-base.conf  -- they are not in my file, should I add them? I followed your steps but still no sound. The systemctl commands showed problems: e.g. 'pipewire[2497]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnkn'

yes add them, missing jackbus is not issue, also can be fixed https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=408389

Thank you for the suggestions; extra lines didn't do anything; jackbus fix didn't work.

Worked for me on a Kogan mini-pc. There was no existing "snd-hda-intel" line
